# Wildfly: Cannot find jboss-cli-logging.properties when adding module with cli

Tags: windows, jboss, command-line-interface, wildfly

I'm trying to add a module to my Wildfly (version 24) server by running:

```
$WILDFLY_24_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --command="module add --name=com.oracle.jdbc --resources=ojdbc8.jar;oraclepki.ja r;osdt_cert.jar;osdt_core.jar;jdbc-extensions.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api,org.jboss.ironjacam ar.jdbcadapters,org.jboss.logging"
```

My computer is running Windows 10, but I'm using the bash emulated by [cmder](https://cmder.net/), therefore I am running `jboss-cli.sh`.

Although it installs the module correctly, an error is displayed:

```
Unable to read the logging configuration from 'file:/c/Applications/wildfly-24.0.0.Final/bin/jboss-cli-logging.properties' (java.io.FileNotFoundException: \c\Applications\wildfly-24.0.0.Final\bin\jboss-cli-logging.properties (The system cannot find the path specified))
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevertheless I'm running an emulated bash, as this is on Windows, it's still necessary to use `jboss-cli.bat`.

Running

```
$WILDFLY_24_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.bat --command="module add --name=com.oracle.jdbc --resources=ojdbc8.jar;oraclepki.j ar;osdt_cert.jar;osdt_core.jar;jdbc-extensions.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api,org.jboss.ironjaca mar.jdbcadapters,org.jboss.logging"
Module com.oracle.jdbc already exists at C:\Applications\wildfly-24.0.0.Final\modules\com\oracle\jdbc\main
```

works flawlessly.